# Intel HD 4600 graphics card not supported in Linux Mint 17

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, intel-graphics

I have just installed Linux Mint 17 on my desktop computer with a Intel HD 4600 graphics card. Unfortunately it only supports a low resolution of 1920 x 1200 which looks horrible in contrast to the monitor's native 2560 x 1440.

I have spend 3 hours googling around trying different suggestions without luck. [This post](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=167352) looked promising but the suggestions didn't help.

Mint 16 boots up in the correct resolution straight from a LiveUSB so something has changed (upstream probably) between the two versions.

There is a [Intel graphics installer](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads) but when I run it, it says "Distribution not supported". I can fake an Ubuntu distro by editing lsb-release and then it installs something but still I can't choose the correct resolution in the Displays utility.

According to the Intel [download center](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?DwnldID=13815) for HD 4600 there is a driver for Linux. But where on earth is the download link on that page? I really can't find it!

What options are there?

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I have tried forcing a new resolution with xrandr but I get a `xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed` when I try to apply the new modes.

Comment: I'd be interested in any feedback you get. I've installed Debian Wheezy on a desktop that has a Gigabyte GA-B85N motherboard with Intel HD4600 Graphics onboard and cannot get it to resume from Standby/Hibernation properly.  The HDMI signal to the monitor is non existent so the monitor stays off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote in my questions that I tried to force the mode with `xrandr` but got an error. I tried to obtain the mode lines with `cvt` and `gtf` which appeared to be the way to get these. But none of the obtained mode lines worked, so I gave up on `xrandr` and tried other solutions.

Actually, I even bought a new graphics card, and while unpacking it, I decided to give the existing card a last chance.

I looked in Xorg.log (like I did several times before) but this time, after trying so many combinations of mode lines, I noticed that the listed mode lines were a bit different than those obtained from `cvt` and `gtf`. Interesting!

So I tried these mode lines with `xrandr` and bingo! I suddenly had a working mode line that forced the resolution into 2560 x 1440.

The last step was to simply add the mode to xorg.conf which looks like this:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "HDMI1"
    Modeline "2560x1440x0.0"  241.50  2560 2608 2640 2720  1440 1443 1448 1481 +hsync -vsync
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "HDMI1"
    Device "Card0"
    Monitor "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Modes "2560x1440x0.0"
        Depth 24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I found [a page in portuguese](http://www.diolinux.com.br/2013/09/como-instalar-os-drivers-graficos-da-intel-no-Linux-Mint.html) that explains a workaround.

Before running the Intel Installer change your /etc/lsb-release and input those contents:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 17 Qiana"
```

Install the drivers and revert the changes on the file.

After a reboot:

```
$ sudo su
# lshw -c video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:60 memory:b0000000-b03fffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:3000(size=64)
```

The driver is shown as "i915" that is the module installed. \o/

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that.